# Excel: How to gather unique values in one column that are associated with duplicates in another column?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerquery

With data such as this:

```
Column A     Column B
1               98
1               12
1               21 
1               31   
2               37
2               40
3               48 
4               34
4               88
4               74 
4               99
7               82
7               19
7               29
7               50 
7               95
7               85
```

where all values in `Column B` are unique, and `Column A` has multiple duplicates. How can I group the A values in one column, and display concatenated values of B in another, like this:

```
Column C   Column D
1             98,12,21,31
2             37,40
3             48
4             34,88,74,99
7             82,19,29,50,95,85
```

I've tried with a combination of concatenate and index and match, but it all just turns into a mess.

Any suggestions would be great?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Updated Answer**:

As per date of writing, MS introduced a new `GROUPBY()` function to Excel which is able to aggregate the different values like so:

```
=GROUPBY(A1:A17,B1:B17,ARRAYTOTEXT,,0)
```

---

**Original Answer**:

Let me add two additional methods to the answer by @Harun24HR. Both options assume you don't have headers as per your sample data.

---

**Option 1)** : Dynamic Array Functions

When one has access to dynamic array functions you may use the following:

In `C1`:

```
=UNIQUE(A1:A17)
```

This [`UNIQUE`](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-unique-function) function will [spill](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/dynamic-array-formulas-and-spilled-array-behavior-205c6b06-03ba-4151-89a1-87a7eb36e531) an array of unique values from defined range into column C.

In `D1`:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,FILTER(B$1:B$17,A$1:A$17=C1))
```

Whereas [`FILTER`](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-filter-function) will extract all values from column B where column A matches it is [`TEXTJOIN`](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-textjoin-function) that will concatenate these values into your desired string.

Drag down...

Or, in a single go, exploiting [`TOCOL()`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/tocol-function-22839d9b-0b55-4fc1-b4e6-2761f8f122ed):

```
=LET(x,UNIQUE(TOCOL(A:A,1)),HSTACK(x,MAP(x,LAMBDA(y,TEXTJOIN(",",,FILTER(B:B,A:A=y))))))
```

---

**Option 2)** : [PowerQuery](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/getting-started-with-power-query-7104fbee-9e62-4cb9-a02e-5bfb1a6c536a?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

Would you want to experiment with *PowerQuery/GetAndTransform* then you don't need any formulas nor `VBA` for that matter. Follow these steps:

- Select `A1:B17` and from the ribbon choose `Data` > `From Table/Range` under "Get & Transform Data"
- Choose to import data without headers. A new window will open.
- From the ribbon click `Transform` > `Group By`. Within that menu choose to group by Column1, choose a new column name, e.g.: "Grouped" and then choose `All Rows` from the Operation dropdown and click `OK`.
- You'll notice an extra column. Now on the ribbon click `Add Column` > `Custom Column` and enter the following formula: `Table.Column([Grouped], "Column2")`. This should add a third column that holds a list of values.
- Remove `Grouped` from the table. Then click on the icon to the right of the newly added column name, and you'll have two options. Choose `Extract Values`, then choose a comma as your delimiter.

There might be a translation-error in the M-code below, but this should be it:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Tabel1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", Int64.Type}, {"Column2", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Column1"}, {{"Grouped", each _, type table [Column1=number, Column2=number]}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Custom", each Table.Column([Grouped], "Column2")),
    #"Extracted Values" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Custom", {"Custom", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), ","), type text}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Extracted Values",{"Grouped"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

PowerQuery is available from Excel-2010 if I'm not mistaken so you wouldn't need access to advanced formulas like `TEXTJOIN` to perform this.

Comment: Thank you! I went for the power querty option and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 8):

First, you need to extract unique value from `Column A` to `Column C`. You can do it by using `Advance Filter` method or you can use below formula.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$18,MATCH(0,INDEX(COUNTIF($C$1:C1,$A$2:$A$18),0,0),0)),"")
```

After extracting unique values you have to use `TEXTJOIN()` formula to aggregate values from `Column B` to `Column D`. You have `TEXTJOIN()` formula in your excel version then you can use it like below

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF($A$2:$A$18=C2,$B$2:$B$18,""))
```

Otherwise you have to user `VBA` custom function to write `TextJoin()` formula. For `TEXTJOIN()` custom function you can have look to this post. [Post Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45843881/textjoin-udf-for-excel-2013)

[image]