# Transpose data separated with ';' in Excel or Google Sheets

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I have my data like this:

```
Main ID    SUB ID    Info

1A         1A1     24572-16
1A         1A1     26553-17
1A         1A2     24572-16
```

I would like to return like this: IF 'info' have the same 'SUB ID' and 'MAIN ID'

return like this:

```
Main ID    SUB ID     Info

1A         1A1     24572-16; 26553-17
1A         1A2     24572-16
```

Is it something possible?

Comment: Have a look over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60772717/9758194). You basically need to go over the PowerQuery steps and you are done. Just realize you need to group by both column 1 and column 2 in step 3 of option 2.

Answer (score 0):

If you want output result in separate cells then use below formula.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($C$2:$C$4,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($1:$3)/(($A$2:$A$4=$E2)*($B$2:$B$4=$F2)),COLUMN(A$1))),"")
```

[image]

> If you want to get output result in same cell then you have to use [TEXTJOIN()](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-textjoin-function) function.

Comment: I can get it work... Thanks for the help1 https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uCGu9cCQWJMpU2a0hD6u81DyYY9SAPFlCL9DveSy4Pc/edit#gid=0