# Creating multiple columns for different values in 1 single row

Tags: excel

this is pretty simple and I can't get my head around how to do it! I'm trying to do a:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,G:G)
```

But not sure how to group it by business.

In excel, I have a data set which is like the below:

| Business | Location |
| --- | --- |
| Mary's | United Kingdom |
| Mary's | United States |
| Mary's | Canada |
| Bill's | Bolivia |
| Bill's | Canada |
| Adam's | Iceland |
| Adam's | United States |

But for each of these businesses, I need to convert it to this:

| Business | Location |
| --- | --- |
| Mary's | United Kingdom, United States, Canada |
| Bill's | Bolivia, Canada |
| Adam's | Iceland, United States |

Can anyone give any tips?

Thanks!

Comment: `TEXTJOIN`........

Comment: Thanks - I'm trying to use that but because I have a massive dataset with different numbers of locations it's not working how I'd expect it to. That's fine for this example but to try use it against 10000ish rows it's not producing the right results?

Comment: You will need to do it in two steps, fist get the unique list then use textjoin on that unique list.

Comment: Thanks - I've edited with a bit more info. I'm used to working with SQL if that's any easier?

Comment: Look into Powerquery.

Comment: `=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,FILTER(G:G,F:F="Mary's"))`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60772285/9758194

Comment: The PowerQuery worked excellently, and now I know something new! Thanks for all that suggested and thanks for the link! :)