# Reference for a dynamic range

Tags: excel-formula

I have a table A2:E7, where each column comes from a dynamic array formula. As a result, `=A2#`, `=B2#`, etc. work and spill.

Now, I would like to use `TEXTJOIN` over each row, the expected results are in column F. But `=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,A2:E2#)` does not work. I don't know how to write the dynamic reference for a range.

Could anyone help?

[image]

Comment: I think you can easily reuse the formula that causes the spill and wrap it in textjoin: `=TEXTJOIN(",",1,YourFormulaInA2)`

Comment: @P.b `YourFormulaInA2` does not cover columns B to E.

Comment: I recently fell into the same need when trying to create a solution for all combinations of a variable element array. I finally made a ridiculous brute force solution that broke out each column such that the formula had to be rewritten for each set of column dimensions (e.g. 3, 4, 5...). I never found a solution, so I will be watching this one. Good luck - it's a great problem to solve.

Comment: @markfitzpatrick let's see...

Comment: what I just posted has a flaw - it assumes 1 character cells. will think about how to go around that.

Comment: @SoftTimur - I looked at nearly the same problem only just last weekend. I gave up in frustration and thought that I would not find an answer. But as soon as I said to you that i could not solve it, bookmarked it and closed the page, the "what if you parsed a giant text blob" idea came to me. I built a LET formula once that parsed text according to break lines, so I know how that works, so... Your problem is a good general archetype. Thanks for a well thought out problem. Hope it helps others.

Comment: Looking back, my answer may not be *The Answer*. Is there a requirement that the input be A2:E2? If so, my answer would need to discover the spilled columns from their root cells. If the **answer requires A2:E2 as input** and it is **acceptable to have a max number of columns**, there is a solution. **If A2:xxx2 must be the input** where **there is no fixed limit to xxx**, the problem gets hard (again). What do you think? As for solving my earlier problem, the solution below now does that as my input was a single, 2-dimensional dynamic array of variable size.

Comment: I just thought of a way to have A2:xx2 as a range of roots to dynamic arrays that can be the input to your formula.  I will append it to my answer below.

Comment: @SoftTimur - did you even read the answers?

Comment: @markfitzpatrick, hi Mark, I did read the answers. And I do appreciate your help in every question. For this question, I did have a little bit of hesitance, that's why I did not accept anything immediately... It does happen...

Comment: Thanks @SoftTimur - just no feedback until now.

Comment: Cheers, ST! :-) That is probably the only referential work I've done here. The question is great and it keeps showing up time-after-time. It is not immediately evident, but to answer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68812918/how-to-summarize-data-with-each-data-change/68824642#68824642) one requires an answer to your original question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Previous Answer**

*this one has a flaw: it assumes 1 char cell values, but I am leaving it here for reference. New answer below.*

You could do:

```
=LET( m, A2:E7,
       rSeq, SEQUENCE( ROWS(m) ),
       L, MMULT( LEN(m),SIGN( SEQUENCE( COLUMNS(m) ) ) )*2-1,
       i, MMULT(--( TRANSPOSE( rSeq ) < rSeq ), L ) + rSeq - 1,
       MID( TEXTJOIN( ",", TRUE, m ), i+1, L ) )
```

**Revised Answer**

This can take variably sized cell values:

```
=LET( m, A2:E7,
       rSeq, SEQUENCE( ROWS(m) ),
       L, MMULT( LEN(m)--(m<>""), SIGN( SEQUENCE( COLUMNS(m) ) ) ) - 1,
       i, MMULT(--( TRANSPOSE( rSeq ) < rSeq ), L ) + rSeq,
       IFERROR( MID( TEXTJOIN( ",", TRUE, m ), i, L ), "" ) )
```

> added @P.b's IFERROR wrapper to prevent blank rows from throwing a
> VALUE error. - Thanks P.b! Nice catch.

There may still be some places for optimization.  Basically, it does a giant TEXTJOIN at the the end that concatenates everything with "," delimiters. With that in mind, it prepares some arrays that will be used to break up the giant text blob. **L** creates an array of lengths of each cell value as well as its delimiter (less 1). **i** is an index that simply adds up L's values consecutively into a columnar array to tell the MID function where to break while L tells MID the size of each chunk of the giant text blob.

> NB: If the delimiter is more than 1 character, this fails.

[image]

**Expanding Roots Method**

If the requirements are:

- The input must be a row of cells that each contain dynamic arrays that are spilled below.
- The number of columns is variable, but contiguous.
- The delimiter is one character.
- All input cells are dynamic arrays of one column dimension.
- All dynamic arrays are equally sized.§

Then this formula should work:

```
=LET( root, A2:E2,
       c, COLUMNS(root),
       m, IFERROR( INDEX(root,1,1):INDEX(root,1,c)#, "" ),
       rSeq, SEQUENCE( ROWS(m) ),
       L, MMULT( LEN(m)--(m<>""), SIGN( SEQUENCE( c ) ) ) - 1,
       i, MMULT(--( TRANSPOSE( rSeq ) < rSeq ), L ) + rSeq,
       IFERROR( MID( TEXTJOIN( ",", TRUE, m ), i, L ), "" ) )
```

where **root** (A2:E2) is the input range that contains the roots of each dynamic array.

> § - If they are not equally sized, the underlaps will contain 0's.
> This can be fixed by replacing 0 with "", but if your inputs would
> normally contain valid 0's, this would be a bad approach, so I left
> that out and maintained a requirement of equal length dynamic arrays
> as inputs instead. If you require variable length arrays, with zeros,
> it's possible, but will add more steps that could slow it down.

### LAMBDA METHOD

So... finally LAMBDA is here and the above problem can now be solved by this single line formula:

```
=BYROW(A2:E7,LAMBDA(x,TEXTJOIN(",",1,x)))
```

crazy...

Comment: Just brilliant!

Comment: Merci, @P.b - really appreciate the encouragement. I may have found a way to fix the variable length cell values. Getting real close at the moment.

Comment: PS if you wrap it in `=IFERROR(brillianformula,"")` it throws a blank value if one row doesn't contain values (even the first row in range).

Comment: Cheers @P.b! I just saw your comment after I posted the new version. I will edit again and add the IFERROR. How did you even find that? Great stuff!

Comment: I was just trying out your formula for better understanding and tweaked the data a bit. Cheers on finding the solution you had in mind.

Comment: Holy crap!!!.  I would never have thought of spliting the TEXTJOIN result to make it spill correctly.  I tip my hat to you sir.

Comment: WOW! I have screenshot this one. - Cheers, @ScottCraner - I had actually given up on this one and then it occurred to me "what if"...

Comment: BTW, I found this because your answer was linked [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68593938/row-wise-textjoin-of-dynamic-array-with-lookup/68594284#68594284)

Comment: @ScottCraner This is really quite a circle, because the original inspiration was driven by this related OP https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67905393/how-to-generate-all-combinations-using-5-columns-using-a-formula-in-excel/67926177#67926177 that referenced your original work. It has the same base problem, but I found no solution. This above OP helped me find the solution, but there remains one more problem to solve, which you already commented --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68400019/excel-dynamic-array-formula-to-create-a-running-product-of-a-column

Comment: Afterwards, by chance, I stumbled upon this OP https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67190244/use-textjoin-with-filter-and-reference-to-a-spill-range/68312099#68312099 and used the above answer to address it.