# Row-wise textjoin of dynamic array with lookup

Tags: arrays, excel, lookup, textjoin, spill-range

This question is closely related to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68198352/reference-for-a-dynamic-range/68201010#68201010) from user [mark fitzpatrick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4617121/mark-fitzpatrick).

My sheet image
[image]

I have a variable list of country code headers in M3# and AB3# (same list) and a variable list of unique "mentions" as rows in A4#. The formulas in M4# and AB4# count the number of times a specific mention from A4# was listed for each country for two questions, *"P"* and *"O"* respectively. Each mention is present in at least one of *"P"* or *"O"*. For each row in columns L and AA, I have a formula to textjoin each row's mention count per country for *"P"* and *"O"* separately (if no mentions, then "-"), but this is not a dynamic formula - I have to copy it down the range of mentions each time the range is updated.

**I want columns L and AA to instead contain dynamic formulas. How do I update Mark's formula in columns AM and AN to contain country codes like in columns L and AA?**

In AM4# and AN4#, I am using [Mark's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4617121/mark-fitzpatrick) updated formula on my spilled ranges M4# and AB4# which produce the same result as my individual formulas, except without the country codes:

```
=LET( m, M4#,
   rSeq, SEQUENCE( ROWS(m) ),
   L, MMULT( LEN(m)--(m<>""), SIGN( SEQUENCE( COLUMNS(m) ) ) ) - 1,
   i, MMULT(--( TRANSPOSE( rSeq ) < rSeq ), L ) + rSeq,
   IFERROR( MID( TEXTJOIN( ",", TRUE, m ), i, L ), "" ) )
```

(edited to remove unnecessary intro)

Comment: BTW: commenting on a previous answer to get guidance on your own problem is not appropriate.  You have done the appropriate thing by asking your own question regardless of rep.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance, I'll be sure to make my own posts in the future as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

concatenate the title to the range:

```
=LET( m, M4#&IF(M4#<>""," "&$M$3:$T$3,""),
   rSeq, SEQUENCE( ROWS(m) ),
   L, MMULT( LEN(m)--(m<>""), SIGN( SEQUENCE( COLUMNS(m) ) ) ) - 1,
   i, MMULT(--( TRANSPOSE( rSeq ) < rSeq ), L ) + rSeq,
   IFERROR( MID( TEXTJOIN( ",", TRUE, m ), i, L ), "" ) )
```

where `$M$3:$T$3` is your titles.

[image]

---

**Edit:**

To add the space we need to do some changes.  I moved the desired splitter to its own variable so I can find the length of it:

```
=LET( m, M4#&IF(M4#<>""," "&$M$3:$T$3,""),
   spl,", ",
   rSeq, SEQUENCE( ROWS(m) ),
   L, MMULT( LEN(m)+(m<>"")*LEN(spl), SIGN( SEQUENCE( COLUMNS(m) ) ) ) - LEN(spl),
   i, MMULT(--( TRANSPOSE( rSeq ) < rSeq ), L ) + ((rSeq-1)*LEN(spl)) + 1,
   IFERROR( MID( TEXTJOIN( spl, TRUE, m ), i, L ), "" ) )
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is very close to what I'm after! Can you share an edit that will result in "1 B, 1 C" with a space between the comma and "1 C", but no extra space if there is only 1 country code?

Comment: This is excellent, but....looks like in the new formula you pasted, the comma after spl,"," is missing. Your formula in the screenshot does work though. Thank you! Marked as answer.

Comment: @dholt you are correct I missed it.  Edited to add.

Answer (score 0):

What about a simpler function on each row, like we used to?

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,FILTER(RowData&" "&$Country$Codes, RowData))
```