# How to summarize data with each data change?

Tags: excel-formula

Can somebody help me with this? In the first column I have a serial number, and in the second column - start number of the interval (which are less than in the third column), and in the third column - the end number. Now, I need to summarize the start number and end number according to their serial number which come are in sequence. Thank You in advance!

1. **301** 1 15
2. **301** 16 25
3. **301** 26 50
4. **301** 51 60
5. **300** 71 80
6. **300** 81 90
7. **300** 91 100
8. **303** 200 250
9. **303** 251 300
10. **303** 301 350
11. **303** 351 370
12. **301** 500 520
13. **301** 521 550
14. **301** 551 600

e.g.

- **301** 1-60
- **300** 71-100
- **303** 200-370
- **301** 500-600

Comment: Please post the data as actual data, so we can easily reproduce and also it makes it more helpful if someone has a similar problem in the future. Also, what have you tried yourself?

Comment: The actual data is similar to this one with the only difference that it consists of 8 digits. The serial number is the same.

Answer (score -1):

I would do the following (I assume your data is in A1:C100, and your results start in E1):

1. `=UNIQUE($A$1:$A$100)` to get all the unique serial numbers
2. `=MIN(FILTER($B$1:$B$100, $A$1:$A$100=$E1))` to get the minimums for each serial number
3. `=MAX(FILTER($C$1:$C$100, $A$1:$A$100=$E1))` to get the maximums for each serial number