# Excel 2013 | List content of non-blank cells in array

Tags: excel

In Excel 2013 I need to have the content of the cells on the array A9:E18 listed in the cells from H1 to H10 (because I already  know that there will always be exactly 10 non-blank cells in that array, the rest of them being empty).
I cannot find a proper formula to have it done.
Could anybody help me, please?

Comment: Can post some sample data?

Comment: There are no data yet, I'm simply building the structure of it. The cells will be populated by  text values. Perhaps I haven't explained correctly the situation, my bad. The array A9:E18 will have only empty cells BUT 10 of them which will be populated by text values. I need to have these 10 values to be listed from H1 to H10.

Comment: Can you please check my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use `FILTERXML()` with `TEXTJOIN()` function. Unfortunately `Excel2013` doesn't have `TEXTJOIN()` function. You can use a custom `TEXTJOIN()` function from this article [TextJoin UDF For Excel 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45845229/5514747)
 of @Scott Craner answer. Then use `FILTERXML()` like below.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",TRUE,$A$1:$E$18)&"</s></t>","//s"),ROW($A1)),"")
```

With <kbd>Excel365</kbd> you can simply use-

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",TRUE,$A$1:$E$18)&"</s></t>","//s")
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately it's not properly working, just giving me back only 3 results out of the expected 10.

Comment: Then there is problem with your data. Which formula you used?

Comment: This one, =IFERROR(INDEX(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",TRUE,$A$1:$E$18)&"</s></t>","//s"),ROW($A1)),"") just using ; instead of , and modifying the array to $A$9:$E$18 and ROW($A9) because my data are in the array A9:E18.

Comment: Fixed the error myself, I had modified ROW($A1) into ROW($A9) where it needed to stay that way. Now it works, thank you a lot for your help :)

Comment: Glad to know it helps.