# How to turn a 2D array, based on some conditions, into a list (like a column)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This question is a more general approach of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66949443/excel-2013-list-content-of-non-blank-cells-in-array):

The original question says:

> I have a 2D array, and I want to see the blank cells in one column.

I would like to generalise this into:

> I have a 2D array, and I want to see the cells, satisfying a condition, in one column.

Is there a general approach for this?

As an example, let's take this:

```
      A    B    C    D
   ==== ==== ==== ====
1 |   1   12    3    4
2 |  11   22   53   34
3 |   1   32   33    4
```

Imagine I'd like to list values, smaller than 5, in a column.

The result would need to be:

```
1
3
4
1
4
(without empty cells in between)
```

Is there a general approach (I mean a formula, not a VBA macro) for this?

Comment: What is your excel version?

Comment: I'm working with Excel 365.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `FILTERXML()` & `TEXTJOIN()` if your version of excel supports.

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",TRUE,A1:D3)&"</s></t>","//s[.<5]")
```

- `<t>` & `<s>` are used to make a xml string. We can use any charecter like `<x>`, `<y>` but must be in vaild xml format.
- Here `"<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",TRUE,A1:D3)&"</s></t>"` will construct a valid `xml` string to process by `FILTERXML()`.
- `//s` will return all s node while `[.<5]` will filter only nodes less than `5`.

More about `FILTERXML()` here from @JvdV [Extract substrings from string using FILTERXML()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61837696/excel-extract-substrings-from-string-using-filterxml)

[image]

Comment: What's the meaning of the tags `<s>` and `<t>`? Is there a link between the tag `<s>` and the formulated condition `s[.<5]`? (Sorry, but I don't know the `FILTERXML()` function that well)