# How can I get cell address with duplicate values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, data-analysis

In a column, there are multiple cells with duplicate values.
How can I get cell address with duplicate values?

For example in the sample below Apple is repeated in B2, B5, B7

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If one has the dynamic array formula TEXTJOIN and FILTER:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,"B" & FILTER(ROW($B$2:$B$8),$B$2:$B$8=B2))
```

[image]

Since there is a version that has TEXTJOIN and not FILTER:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,"B" & IF($B$2:$B$8=B2,ROW($B$2:$B$8),""))
```

This would only work in Excel 2019 and will require the use of Ctrl-Shift-Enter to force an array formula.

If one does not have TEXTJOIN look [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45843881/textjoin-udf-for-excel-2013/45845229#45845229) for a UDF that mimics TEXTJOIN and use the second formula with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

Comment: Sorry to ask, will it be possible,In place of cell address I can get, values in column A as comma-separated.

Comment: sure, just change the `ROW($B$2:$B$8)` to `$A$2:$A$8` and remove the `"B" & `