# How to construct a lookup loop in Excel (without using VBA)?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have data in an excel sheet, which follows the below pattern:

[image]

As you can see, each employee ha a manager, who is an employee himself. There are employees reporting to an employee who reports to another (for eg. H reports to D, who reports to B, who in turn reports to E reporting to Z.

What I am looking for is a way I can find all the employees who are "under" a given person. For example, if I supply the formula with E, then it should find me the employees who report to E (A, B and I), those who report to A/B/I (C, D), those who report to C/D (H).

I am not too confident with my excel skills, having used only basic VLOOKUP, but have failed to come up with a way to do this sort of lookups within lookups.

Answer (score 1):

With Microsoft365, I used the following:

[image]

Formula in `D2`:

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTER(A$2:A$12,IFERROR(MMULT(--(B$2:B$12=D1#),SEQUENCE(COUNTA(D1#),,,0)),B$2:B$12=D1),""))
```

Dragged down untill you hit empty cells.

Comment: H reports to D. Why is it under C?

Comment: It's not perse under `C`. It's just those who report to any of those in the line above them @Jayachandran

Comment: Thank You for your response. Upvoting. I will accept if this solution is applicable to Excel 2013.

Comment: @Jayachandran, it won't be. It's a Microsoft365 solution. I'd recommend adding your version of Excel to your tags to specify this.

Answer (score 0):

In E2, array formula (Ctrl+Shift+Enter) copied across right to G2 :

=TEXTJOIN(", ",,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($B2:$B12,D2)),$A2:$A12,""))

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For <kbd>Excel2013</kbd> you can use `AGGREGATE()` function. As per my below screenshot use formulas

```
D2=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$12,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($1:$12)/($B$2:$B$12=$D$1),ROW(1:1))),"")
E2=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$12,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($1:$12)/($B$2:$B$12=D2),ROW($1:$1))),"")
```

Copy down and across as needed. If you want to show values in same cell with comma separated then you need to use `TEXTJOIN()` custom function for `Excel2013` as Textjoin is not available on `Excel2013`. Here is link of `TEXTJOIN()` from @Scott Craner

[TextJoin UDF For Excel 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45845229/5514747)

[image]