# How to replace TEXTJOIN() in Excel for older versions?

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-365

I have an Excel sheet that works well where I use TEXTJOIN() which is only available in the latest Excel versions. Is there an easy way to transform it to use existing functions of older Excel versions?

My code looks like this:

```
TEXTJOIN(", ";TRUE;IF(INDIRECT("'"&C5&"'"&"!$E$88:$E$239")="Yes";INDIRECT("'"&C5&"'"&"!$D$88:$D$239");"")
```

Comment: Custom `UDF` is alternative option. You can read this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45845229/5514747) from Scott Craner.

Comment: The "&" also does concatenation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to combine the formulas `IF()` and `CONCATENATE()`

Comment: But how do I do this from E88 to E239. Do I have to check every row?

Comment: @Theodeo check array formulas [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7?ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB)