# Striving to Add 0 to complete the string number to 3

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I have data set which i want to convert from this. I have tried with custom formatting but its result is different.

```
=TEXT(A1,"000")

Data
.3.11.333
.3.3.3.3
11.33.1
```

to this

```
Result
003.011.333
003.003.003.003
011.033.001
```

Comment: I also try to do it with TEXT function but not sure how it will work. Yes these are numeric values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your data I don't actually think you are dealing with numbers, but text that includes numeric characters. Maybe your best bet is to "split" your data into an array before using `TEXT()`, and then join them back together:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=TEXTJOIN(".",,TEXT(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[.*0=0]"),"000"))
```

The point here is to only include elements from the array that are actually numeric. We filter them through xpath-expression `[.*0=0]` to avoid the empty string elements from leading or trailing dots.

---

**EDIT:**

This can be poored into an UDF as such:

```
Function REFORMAT(str As String) As String

With Application
    REFORMAT = Join(.Text(.Transpose(.FilterXML("<t><s>" & Replace(str, ".", "</s><s>") & "</s></t>", "//s[.*0=0]")), "000"), ".")
End With

End Function
```

Call through `=REFORMAT(A1)`.

Comment: Thank you very much But I have Excel 2016 which Does not have TextJoin function. But it will be useful to achieve with Excel 365.

Comment: Is formula a must then? Otherwise think about PowerQuery or an UDF?

Comment: You can use `TEXTJOIN()` [UDF](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45845229/5514747) from here by Scott Craner.