# Excel - Create a string from a table

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i'd like to create a string from a table, something similar to this example:

|  | Passed | Failed | Skipped |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Test1 | 13 | 4 | 10 |
| Test2 | 10 | 12 |  |
| Test3 | 20 |  | 9 |
| Test4 |  | 25 | 11 |

From this table i'd like to have this strings like this

|  | String |
| --- | --- |
| Test1 | 13 Passed - 4 Failed - 10 Skipped |
| Test2 | 10 Passed - 12 Failed |
| Test3 | 20 Passed - 9 Skipped |
| Test4 | 25 Failed - 11 Skipped |

Comment: What is it you have tried/researched? Did you do you own due diligence? If so, please edit the post. See [ask] a question with an [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `TEXTJOIN()` function. Try below formula-

```
=TEXTJOIN("-",TRUE,IF(($B$2:$D$5<>"")*($A$2:$A$5=F2),$B$2:$D$5&" " &$B$1:$D$1,""))
```

***Note:*** **TEXTJOIN()** is only available to ***Excel-2019*** and ***Excel365***. For older version you need **Textjoin** UDF.

Here is [TEXTJOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45845229/5514747) user defined function link by Scott Craner

[image]